# Why is Card Expanding even though it's child shouldnt

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

new to flutter and dart, i have a hard time understanding basic layouting...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> widgets = const [Text(""),Text(""),Text(""),Text(""),];
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: widgets,
      ),);
  }
}
```

This is a working sample in DartPad(Flutter). Why is the red thing fully expanding to fit the screen? I would expect it to have the Columns MainAxisSize.min.

I would like to have a layout which takes the full row (with a margin) but only the requested height of its child.

On a side note: I was suggested taking the Card Widget when i try to make something in a "Card style" instead of make everything by myself. The thing is, a Card might add overhead like Text which i don't need. Why should i choose that for that reason?

Thanks

Edit:
Found the solution

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            color: backgroundColor,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: widgets,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? a column of cards with each card having a certain text ?

Comment: The column with your empty Text widgets is MainAxisSize.min, but the widget (Card) it's wrapped in is taking up the entire space offered by the parent. When I started with Flutter I found the layout confusing as well. I'm two Flutter projects in and I still have times it trips me up. Here's the most helpful article I've read, especially the imaginary conversation about size between widgets. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Comment: @AnanSaadi I wanted to have the child widgets  expand all the way on the horizontal level and only use the space in the height they need.

Comment: @Pat9RB
Thanks for the input and the link. Going to check that.
I found the solution to my problem, updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Worked like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            color: backgroundColor,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: widgets,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).